# Can you append an integer onto a Buffer without converting to a string?

Tags: ibm-doors

The only DXL documentation I've found suggests converting to a string

```
Buffer buf = create()
int i = 2
string str = i ""
buf = str
```

Is there a way to skip creating the string and go directly to the Buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you take

```
int i = 2
buf += i""
```

as a solution. Which is basically the same as you do, just without creating an additional variable